# Validate form and formsets with django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I'm trying to set my form validation in my view and I would like to get you help because I have a little issue.

This is my formset :

```
DocumentFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Publication, Document, form=DocumentForm, extra=1, max_num=4, can_delete=True)
```

This is my code :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PublicationCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    document_queryset = Document.objects.all()
    context['FormSets'] = DocumentFormSet(self.request.POST or None, self.request.FILES or None,
                                                  prefix='doc', queryset=document_queryset)
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    try:
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formsets = context['FormSets']
        if form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            if formsets.is_valid():
                formsets.instance = self.object
                formsets.save(commit=False)
                for element in formsets:
                    element.save(commit=False)
            self.object = form.save()
            formsets.save()
        return super(PublicationCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
     except IntegrityError:
         ...
```

I read some things, especially form has to be save before forms in formset if there is ForeignKey between form and forms in my formset.

The issue comes if I have wrong field in my formset. As the first form is saved, it creates an object with only the first form and not with the associated form in my formset.

This is an example :

[image]

As you can see, it saves my first form, but I don't want until all the formset is valid.

I have to switch between `.save(commit=False)` and `.save()` methods.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So, don't save the main form first.

```
if form.is_valid() and formsets.is_valid():
    self.object = form.save()
    formsets.instance = self.object
    formsets.save()
```

(Note, you don't need to save the formset forms individually; just remove the `commit=False` both times.)

Comment: If I replace my part by your part, it just saves the `publication form` while my form `document form` gets error willingly.